# How do you package a puppeteer app?

Tags: puppeteer

I cannot seem to find any way to package a puppeteer nodeJS application into a linux/mac/windows binary?

I tried to use `pkg` but came up with this issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2267

Someone also said to try to use `nw` but I didn't have any luck there either... possibly due to me not knowing that toolkit at all.

Has anyone had any luck doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should to create an external folder of chromium and set the path of executable to init puppeteer. Steps :

1. Create external folder for chromium :

   **cd nodeProject**

   **mkdir chromium**
2. Copy from chromium-pupeteer directory to new external folder :

   **xcopy node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium\win64-756035\ chromium /E /H /I**
3. Set the path of executable to init puppeteer :

   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ **executablePath: './chromium/chrome.exe'**});
4. Generate the executable package :

   **pkg index.js**

In brief, the executable alway together with chromium folder :

[image: end package]

Comment: For Step #2 - Git Bash command also works: cp -r node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-982053/chrome-win/ chromium